# triangle rule: Determinant of 3rd order

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: Triange rule]

Could anybody help me to draw the picture with TikZ + PGF?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so you should add what you have done

Comment: This looks overly complicated.  [Sarrus' rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) is more intuitive.

Comment: Look into the `matrix` library, the example at [page 309 of the manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) would be a good start.

Comment: For me Sarrus' rule is overcomplicated) I found http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/mnemonic-rule-for-matrix-determinant/

Comment: @Henri Menke: But this is a way of expressing Sarrus' rule.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Long ago, I came to the conclusion that teaching such shortcuts for 3⨉3 matrices is simply a waste of time; these triangles are not easier to remember and to use than direct Laplace expansion. I myself use a personal version of Sarrus' rule, but I never teach it, because students will use it also for larger matrices, notwithstanding any warning the teacher can give.

Comment: @egreg Computing determinants by hand is in general waste of time :)

Comment: OK, friends, lets think how to draw the nice picture, but not to teach students to calculate determinants) I read PGFmanual, still have no good ideas.

Comment: Did you see my comment? All you need to do is read some manual.

Comment: @Bernard You might be right.  I only know [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sarrus_rule.svg) representation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it is best to use the TikZ `matrix` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% for guillemets
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes,left delimiter=|,right delimiter=|,
  row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
  nodes={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},nodes in empty cells] (m) at (0,0) {
    & & \\
    & & \\
    & & \\
  };
  \draw (m-2-1) -- (m-3-2);
  \draw (m-1-1) -- (m-3-3);
  \draw (m-1-2) -- (m-2-3);
  %
  \draw (m-1-2) -- (m-3-1);
  \draw (m-1-3) -- (m-3-2);
  %
  \draw (m-2-1) -- (m-1-3);
  \draw (m-3-1) -- (m-2-3);

  \matrix[matrix of nodes,left delimiter=|,right delimiter=|,
  row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
  nodes={draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt},nodes in empty cells] (n) at (5em,0) {
    & & \\
    & & \\
    & & \\
  };
  \draw (n-2-3) -- (n-3-2);
  \draw (n-1-3) -- (n-3-1);
  \draw (n-1-2) -- (n-2-1);
  %
  \draw (n-1-2) -- (n-3-3);
  \draw (n-1-1) -- (n-3-2);
  %
  \draw (n-2-3) -- (n-1-1);
  \draw (n-3-3) -- (n-2-1);

  \node at (0.0em,-2em) {<<$+$>>};
  \node at (2.5em,0 |- m.base) {$,$};
  \node at (5.0em,-2em) {<<$-$>>};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: It's great, exactly Like I dreamed! So quickly, thank you.